# Time between order date

Tags: microstrategy

I need to know how much time passed between one order and another, I only have one attribute for order date and can't make any change in the tables so I need to make this inside a dashboard.

My data looks like this

```
   CLIENT     |  ORDER DATE
   
                 1/26/2018
                 8/12/2018
    Juan Perez   1/2/2019
                 4/26/2019
                 7/9/2020
   -------------------------
                 7/18/2018
    John Doe     3/5/2020
```

[Actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqtxI.png)

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfectly clear what you want to do with the data on hand and to which extent you have control over your environment.
In the simplest of cases you could use "LAG", although with this approach you are not at liberty to remove either CLIENT or ORDER DATE from the grid template:

```
Metric "metric (max(ORDER DATE))": Max([ORDER DATE]){~+}
Metric "Lagging order Date": Lag<BreakBy={@auto, [CLIENT]}, SortBy=(@auto)>([metric (max(ORDER DATE))];1;[metric (max(ORDER DATE))])
Metric "Days Between Orders": DaysBetween([Lagging order Date];[metric (max(ORDER DATE))])
```

If you have other questions like "What is the timespan between first and last order by client?" you would obviously have to tackle this differently, but there is a plethora of possible questions and you were not very specific with what you really need.

```
Timespan between last/first per client?
Metric "min(order date)": Min([ORDER DATE]){~+, [CLIENT]+, ![ORDER DATE]+}
Metric "max(order date)": Max([ORDER DATE]){~+, [CLIENT]+, ![ORDER DATE]+}
Metric "max-min (order date)": [max(order date)]-[min(order date)]
```

These should all work inline, i.e. inside a Dossier.

If you have all of the capabilities of MSTR at your disposal you could also use a Freeform-SQL report and do all kinds of (DB-related) transformations which should allow you to answer any question you have.